# In Silverlight, How can I disable Back and Forward navigation using browser buttons?

Tags: silverlight, navigation-framework

I'm using the Navigational Framework in Silverlight 4.  I'm starting to believe that this was a mistake as the browser buttons are really screwing things up for users.  For instance, when a child window is opened the user believes they can close the window by pressing the back button.  It doesn't close the window obviously, it just navigates the parent page back a step.  The end result is a messed up data set.  I'm fed up with the little control I have over the navigation of my application; forward and back buttons are anachronistic. Web applications don't work that way anymore.  Please someone tell me how I can disable their functionality; that is, cancel navigation when it is started from one of these buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Remove this code from your html page which holds your silverlight XAP:

```
<iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
```

This is the history frame.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to do this in the actual web/asp.net page, as Silverlight has no real control over the browser.

Some workarounds in this article:

http://lennilobel.wordpress.com/2009/07/26/defeat-the-evil-back-button-in-your-asp-net-applications/

Comment: I'm talking about a little thing called deep navigation. It is a component of the Navigational Framework.  I should have mentioned that perhaps.